# dplyr, summarise categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to summarise my data `small` for each different video.id using `dplyr`.

```
small %>% 
  group_by(Video.ID) %>% 
  summarise(sumr = sum(Partner.Revenue),
            len = mean(Video.Duration..sec.),
            cat = mean(Category))
```

mean(Category) is clearly the wrong approach. How do I get it just to use the value that is repeated several times (one video.id has always the same category no matter how often it appears in the dataframe).

My dataframe looks like this :

```
small

# A tibble: 6 x 7
     X1  X1_1 Video.ID    Video.Duration..sec. Category Owned.Views Partner.Revenue
  <int> <int> <chr>                      <int> <chr>          <int>           <dbl>
1     1     1 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            6               0
2     2     2 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            6               0
3     3     3 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            2               0
4     4     4 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            1               0
5     5     5 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            1               0
6     6     6 ---0zh9uzSE                 1184 gadgets            3               0

small <- 
  structure(list(X1 = 1:6, 
                 X1_1 = 1:6, 
                 Video.ID = c("---0zh9uzSE", "---0zh9uzSE", "---0zh9uzSE", "---0zh9uzSE", "---0zh9uzSE", "---0zh9uzSE"), 
                 Video.Duration..sec. = c(1184L, 1184L, 1184L, 1184L, 1184L, 1184L), 
                 Category = c("gadgets", "gadgets", "gadgets", "gadgets", "gadgets", "gadgets"), 
                 Owned.Views = c(6L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), 
                 Partner.Revenue = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), 
            row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of `dput(head(small))` into the question to make it better [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). And also share a small example of expected output.

Comment: i hope that helps,  I dont know yet how to produce expected output.

Comment: @hmmmbob I'll suggest you can use count for Category. Something like for each Category how many videos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have at least two options to solve this:

Add the Category column to your `group_by`:

```
small %>% 
  group_by(Video.ID, cat = Category) %>% 
  summarise(sumr = sum(Partner.Revenue),
            len = mean(Video.Duration..sec.))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   Video.ID [?]
#     Video.ID    cat      sumr   len
#     <chr>       <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 ---0zh9uzSE gadgets     0  1184
```

Or use `unique(Catregory)`:

```
small %>% 
  group_by(Video.ID) %>% 
  summarise(sumr = sum(Partner.Revenue),
            len = mean(Video.Duration..sec.),
            cat = unique(Category))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
#   Video.ID     sumr   len cat    
#   <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
# 1 ---0zh9uzSE     0  1184 gadgets
```

The first option, might be perferred, because it still works if you have multiple categories per id.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a unique category for each `video_id`, you can have `cat = Category[1]`, as in

```
small %>% group_by(Video.ID) %>% 
      summarise(sumr=sum(Partner.Revenue), len = mean(Video.Duration..sec.), 
      cat = Category[1])

# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  Video.ID     sumr   len cat    
#  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  
#  1 ---0zh9uzSE     0  1184 gadgets
```